# What is the difference between access a method -> and access a method ::

Tags: php, methods, call

What is the basic difference between calling a method using `->` and `::`

```
 class a 
  {
    function b()
     {
         echo "abc"; 
     }
  }
```

What is the difference between these two?

1. `a::b();`
2. `$c = new a; $c->b();`

Answer (score 1):

`->` executes the method in the context of an instance, while `::` accesses the method in static context of a class. The latter only has access to static members of the class via `self::`, while the former can also use the instance members via `$this->`.

Answer (score 1):

When defining your class, you should be explicitly declare the visibility of your properties and methods, and whether or not they are static.

The class in your example should be:

```
class A 
{
    public static function b() {
        echo "abc"; 
    }
}
```

The method b() should be static because it doesn't refer to any instance variables. To call b() you would use:

```
A::b();
```

If your method was to use an instance variable (a non-static property) your class would probably look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar;   // non static instance variable

    public function __construct($bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;  // instance variable set in the constructor
    }

    public function baz() {
        echo $this->bar;  // instance variable referred to in the non-static method
    }
}
```

Then you would call the function like this:

```
$x = new Foo('abc');
$x->baz();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     a::b();
> ```

The above statement used to call static method in the context of class(independent of any object cotext) thus $this is not available in static method

> ```
>     $c = new a; $c->b();
> ```

The above satement used to call instance method in the context of object($c) thus $this(refer to object $c) is available inside instance method

Thanks